# Gala Background services Icon

Tags: gala

New install of eos.

On every boot it shows a temporary icon that says...Gala Background services

The icon disappears after about 10 seconds.

How do I disable this????

Answer (score 2):

If you load appeditor from the App center you can go into Gala Background Services and deselect "Show in launcher".  I had the same problem last week.

Comment: I don't see appeditor in the App Center?

Comment: Lol!  App center search is such a mess.  Appeditor is a curated app but it doesn't show if I search on "app" or "appeditor".  Search on "menu" :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply.

'Show in Launcher' was not selected...I toggled it on and then off and saved.

it worked.

Thanks